# Css hover effect different between chrome & Safari

Tags: html, css

I'm new at website development.

Here is **[my website](http://www.legenddesign-hk.com/eng/)**. I see a difference between Chrome and Safari of my menu hover effect.

It was right before.

Can anyone give some help to me?

[image: Difference]

```
.style-dark-override.menu-transparent:not(.is_stuck) .menu-horizontal-inner > .nav > .menu-smart > li > a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

.style-dark-override.menu-transparent:not(.is_stuck) .menu-horizontal-inner > .nav > .menu-smart > li > a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #3bc73b;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**, **clearly** stating which element is problematic and exactly what the difference is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a long term issue about using `display: table-cell` without a table tag as father. Just google that. I try a lot of possible solutions and no one works.

Your issue starts in `col-lg-12 main-menu-container middle` class.

I suggest you to add

```
.menu-legend-main li a
    height: 104px
```

until your mobile breakpoint and that will solve the hover problem. Is not the best solution, but it works pretty well

Comment: Finally i use "Body.hmenu .menu-primary .menu-horizontal .menu-smart>li>a {height:104px} Its help, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and elegant solution to fix the issue just to add some padding top an bottom to your links. For example:

```
body.hmenu .menu-primary .menu-horizontal .menu-smart>li>a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

And I strongly recommend reducing the specificity of CSS selectors.s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!It makes Safari preview out of my control. Because sarfari preview was perfect before.